# C# List which could contain only image or string

Tags: c#, oop, data-conversion

NET developers. 
Decided to make layer to extract some data from data source to build tables in some generated documents further.

Maybe question is simple, but I am confused a little bit.

The problem is - want to build table model which could contain string or image.
At the moment I ended up with that set of classes, but I am not sure that is the proper way:

```
public class TableModel
{
    public long RowsCount { get; set; }

    public long ColumnsCount { get; set; }

    public List<List<DataUnitModel>> Table { get; set; } 
}

public class DataUnitModel
{
    public object Element { get; set; }

    public Type ElementType { get; set; }
}
```

It suppose to be working like that (pseudocode):

```
public void BuildTable(TableModel myTable)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < myTable.Rows)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < myTable.Cols)
        {
            DocumentCurrentRange.Insert(myTable.Table[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

UPD:

Data types - it could be jsut simple strings or jpg/png/bmp images

UPD2:

Txnks guys, realized that I dont need `GetElement` function here its useless.

Comment: Can you show your little data so that we can have idea what data you want to convert?

Comment: @Saadi not sure taht I can tell correctly but I'll update the question

Comment: Is there any advantage in `GetElement()` casting the return value to `Image` or `string` when you return it as `object` anyway? Wouldn't `return model.Element;` do the same?

Comment: What benefit does your `model.GetElement()` have over plain `model.Element`? That said, there are improvements that could be made, both in how to implement that `Element` value and in other parts, but the improvements depend on how you want to use these classes, which to me is not clear enough from your question.

Comment: The basic problem here is: why using the same property for 2 different types?

Comment: @hvd  right, guys, I realize it now - no benefits

Comment: Instead make an interface `IElement`, which the ImageClass and the stringClass both implement, say for example, it has: `GenereateHtml()`. This way for the outside world it doesn't matter if its a stringClass or an ImageClass it just does what it does

Comment: @Pikoh well, I tought it would be like easier to use it?
Just use something like `InsertInTable(element)` and it's just inserting it there without any wrappings

Comment: How do you intend to use this? I.e. what's the end result you are going to build? Doc/HTML reports?

Comment: @Groo yep, exactly

Comment: But why only tables? What about other content (pages, paragraphs, titles, captions)? It seems to me that your report content should be organized hierarchically, and then rendered into different targets (pdf/doc/html) using different renderers. Perhaps you can add some more info about what exactly you are using for rendering, because *that* is what you are trying to solve. Right now, there is little benefit in having your class over simply a `List<List<object>>`.

Comment: @Groo well, in this case I can use something like `DataUnitModel` as it is I guess, and tables are just `DataUnitModel` wrapped in `List<List<>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are taking a slightly wrong approach here, i.e. you are solving the wrong problem. Your "table" could simply be a `List<List<object>>`, and it would essentially carry the same information as your classes are carrying now (apart from the "number of columns", if the list is empty).

If I understood your question, each element type will be "rendered" in some way (as a report, or in a webpage, or converted to something else). If that's true, I would concentrate on defining what's common for a rendering step of all the elements. So, the end result should allow you to write something like:

```
var html = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in document.Items)
{
    // get the renderer for this item type
    var renderer = renderers[item.GetType()];

    // append to the report
    renderer.Append(html, item);
}
```

A simplified report model could be a list of paragraphs, tables, figures, something like:

```xml
<Document>

  <Paragraph>
     Some text
  </Paragraph>

  <Table>
     <HeaderRow>
        <Col>Num</Col> <Col>Name</Col> ...
     <HeaderRow>
     <Row>
        <Col>Num</Col> <Col>Name</Col> ...
     <Row>
  </Table>

  <Image Url="..." />

</Document>
```

Or perhaps each element will have a list of child elements too, but this is a simple example.

Your model would then be expressed with something like:

```cs
interface IDocument 
{
    List<IItem> Items { get; }
}

interface IItem
{
    // common properties which apply to all items
    // (if they don't apply to all items, they
    // shouldn't be here)

    bool CanBreakAcrossPages { get; }
}

interface ITextualItem : IItem
{
    string TextFont { get; }
    float TextSize { get; }
    ...
}

class ParagraphItem : ITextualItem
{
    public bool CanBreakAcrossPages { get; set; }
    public string TextFont { get; set; }
    public float TextSize { get; set; }
    string Text { get; set; }
}

... you get the idea
```

And then, independently, you might have a renderer interface like this:

```
// there are several ways to do this, but this is
// just a simple way to avoid casting all over the 
// code, and still have generics for better type safety

interface IHtmlRenderer
{
    void Append(StringBuilder html, object element);
}

interface IHtmlRenderer<T> : IHtmlRenderer where T : IItem
{
    void Append(StringBuilder html, T element);
}

abstract class BaseHtmlRenderer<T> : IHtmlRenderer<T> where T : IItem
{
    public void Append(StringBuilder html, object element)
    {
        // this is the only place where we will cast
        this.Append(html, (T)element);
    }

    abstract public void Append(StringBuilder html, T element);
}
```

Which then makes creating different renderers obvious:

```
class ParagraphRenderer : BaseHtmlRenderer<ParagraphItem>
{
    public override void Append(StringBuilder html, ParagraphItem element)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

class ImageRenderer : BaseHtmlRenderer<ImageItem>
{
    public override void Append(StringBuilder html, ImageItem element)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And all you are left to do is create a **mapping** of renderers for each `IItem` type (item type -> renderer). This can even be done through reflection/dependency injection, so that everything will "just work" when you decide to create a new renderer type:

```
// this can easily be done automatically through reflection

var renderers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<StringBuilder, object>>();
renderers[typeof(ImageItem)] = new ParagraphRenderer().Append;
renderers[typeof(ParagraphItem)] = new ParagraphRenderer().Append;
```

And now we get to our desired usage:

```
var html = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in document.Items)
{
    // get the renderer for this item type
    var renderer = renderers[item.GetType()];

    // append to the report
    renderer.Append(html, item);
}
```

This brings you to table items, which are interesting in your case, because they can apparently contain images and paragraphs as table cells. This means you could define them something like:

```
class TableItem : ITextualItem
{
    // note the recursion here: 
    // ITableItem is an IItem, and it contains a list of IItems,
    // meaning you can even have nested tables inside a single table cell    

    public List<IItem> HeaderCols { get; }
    public List<List<IItem>> Rows { get; }
}
```

And then the renderer is again interesting because it's a composite (recursive) renderer:

```
public class TableRenderer : BaseHtmlRenderer<TableItem>
{
    // we need to be able to render individual cells
    private Dictionary<Type, Action<StringBuilder, object>> _renderers;

    public override void Append(StringBuilder html, TableItem element)
    {
        RenderHeaderRowStart(html);        
        foreach (var col in element.HeaderCols)
        {
            var cellRenderer = _renderers[col.GetType()];
            cellRenderer.Append(html);
        }
        RenderHeaderRowEnd(html);

        ...
    } 
}
```

Which means you need to pass the dictionary to the renderer constructor:

```
// renderers dictionary contains a TableRenderer, which also keeps
// a reference to this same dictionary
renderers[typeof(TableItem)] = new TableRenderer(renderers).Append;
```

Comment: Wow, I love it! Thats the OOP approach.Seems I get two layer (renderers and models) but thats flexible

Comment: @Danil: well, my idea was to have separate renderers for different targets, so that you could render to different targets separately, but yes, it requires an additional mapping step to connect these two layers. I would say it's slightly more complex to set it up, but easier to extend later. Also, since the model should not know too much about how it will be rendered, perhaps formatting information (e.g. fonts, colors) should not be a part of the model, but rather referenced by renderers only (i.e. HTML output will be one way, Excel the other way, plain text doesn't even need this stuff).

Comment: Whenever I need to present data in some way, I try to imagine all the different formats/media I could encounter (i.e. display it in a simple console app, or as a web page/mobile app/desktop app, or create a report like you're doing now). If the data model seems to contains some data specific to a certain format, then something is wrong and the design needs to be rethinked.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that your extension method `DataUnitModelExtensions.GetElement` does is to make sure that the data contained in `DataUnitModel.Element` is either `Image`, `string` or `null`. Judging from your question, that is the only type of data this property *can* contain. So your extension method essentially does nothing useful. You are using two `as` casts in there which are great for typecasting, but then you return an `object` which makes your typecasts useless.

If you want to expose the content of the `Element` field, use two different properties that return `Image` and `string`. Since you are defing the `DataUnitModel` class yourself, there is no need for extension methods:

```
public class DataUnitModel
{
    public object Element { get; set; }

    public string ElementText { get { return Element as string; } }

    public Image ElementImage { get { return Element as Image; } }

    public Type ElementType { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to get the element type, you can use `GetType` for your `ElementType` property, although some simple `bool` properties would do the job:

```
public class DataUnitModel
{
    public object Element { get; set; }

    public string ElementText { get { return Element as string; } }

    public Image ElementImage { get { return Element as Image; } }

    public Type ElementType { get { Element != null ? Element.GetType() : null; }

    public bool IsElementText { get { return Element is string; } }

    public bool IsElementImage { get { return Element is Image; } }
}
```

Comment: So, in case I need to do something like 
`If (myTable.Table[i][j].IsElementText) ?    DocumentCurrentRange.Insert(myTable.Table[i][j].ElementText) : DocumentCurrentRange.Insert(myTable.Table[i][j].ElementImage);`

Comment: You could do that, but that would be essentially equivalent to `DocumentCurrentRange.Insert(myTable.Table[i][j].Element)`. You can use the `Is...` properties when you want to specifically access a string or an image. As long as `DocumentCurrentRange.Insert` accepts an `obejct`, there is no need for `any` conversion **except** your `Element` property can contain data that is neither string nor Image.

Comment: but what if it would besomething else? Like, well, lets say some `.svg` file? and I want, like, not paste it there in that case. I mean, I think it could be represented as `object` but I dont want to past it there because it will cause exception, lets say

Comment: What do you mean with a svg file? The file contents would be a `byte[]`. To which type would your "svg file" translate?

Comment: let say that we agreggate some stuff from some `DataSource` in this `TableModel`, it could be some `.svg`, `.html` files etc, as `Image` and `strings` as well but, well, so if I would try to use `DocRange.Insert` it would cause exception in case of `svg` or `html`

Comment: so seems like I cant escape of additional checking of type and stuff?

Comment: If you want to just store the data, `object` is fine. If you want to _work_ with _specific data types_, you will have to cast, convert or parse them.

Comment: yes, in this case just to store it! thank you for the explanation
(up but wait a little till maybe some other answer will come)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an interface:

```
public interface IDataUnitModel{}
public class StringDataUnitModel : IDataUnitModel
{
  public string Value {get;set;}
}
public class ImageDataUnitModel : IDataUnitModel
{
  public Image Value {get;set;}
}
//...
public List<IDataUnitModel> list = new List<IDataUnitModel>();
list.Add(new StringDataUnitModel{Value = "ABC"});
list.Add(new ImageDataUnitModel());
```

And while retrieving you can check the type of object. You also can only put in images & strings.

If the table can only contain images or strings you could use generics.

Comment: Oh, sure, thats beautiful! Good :3